# What are the advantages/disatvantages to specify a struct param in a function as calldata vs. memory?

Tags: struct, memory, calldata, function

If I am not modifying the input parameter in the function body are there any reasons a reference type parameter should be labeled as stored in memory?

More generally what are the reasons to go for function foo or bar below. ( the same question goes for other reference types like strings)

```
function foo(StructA calldata asCallData) external {
    ...
}

function bar(StructA memory asMemory) external {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `calldata` is cheaper, consumes less gas.
However, the disadvantage is that you can't **modify** the received data, it's read only.

Example based on your code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract BasicContract {
    struct StructA {
        uint varaiable;
    }

    function foo(StructA calldata asCallData) external {
        asCallData.varaiable++; //This will not work
    }
    
    function bar(StructA memory asMemory) external {
        asMemory.varaiable++; //This will work
    }

}
```

Therefore, if you are just receiving values/data to store it into the contract, using `calldata` is the preferred method:

Case and point:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract BasicContract {

    struct StructA {
       unit varaiable;
    }

    StructA data;

    // Cost: 23817 gas
    function foo(StructA calldata asCallData) external {
        data.varaiable = asCallData.varaiable;
    }

    // Cost: 24182
    function bar(StructA memory asMemory) external {
        data.varaiable = asMemory.varaiable;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes i was aware of that, which is why i phrased it as "If I am not modifying the input parameter in the function body are there any reasons a reference type parameter should be labeled as stored in memory?" . My question is, are there any other considerations